# Replace string only in matched search in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I know you can replace certain patterns in a file using Vim:

```
:%s/<pattern>/<replacement>/g
```

What I want to do is to carry out a pattern replacement ONLY where a secondary search matches, e.g.: if I had the following lines in my file:

```
00_sub_5_train
01_sub_6_train
02_sub_5_train
03_sub_9_train
04_sub_8_train
05_sub_5_train
06_sub_5_train
```

I would want to carry out: `:%s/train/not_train/g` ONLY on the lines where the string 'sub_5' is found such that what remains is:

```
00_sub_5_not_train
01_sub_6_train
02_sub_5_not_train
03_sub_9_train
04_sub_8_train
05_sub_5_not_train
06_sub_5_not_train
```

Is this possible?

Comment: :%s/sub_5/sub_5_not_train/g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly apply the pattern as below. You can fully apply the pattern with *sub_5_train*

```
:%s/sub_5_train/sub_5_not_train/g
```

Based on comment, if you will be having different content post sub_5, you can go for conditional replace like below:

```
:g/sub_5/ s/train/not_train
```

Here, if we find sub_5, we are going for replace for that line only.

Basically, I am trying to utilize g command like below. Here, for `cmd`, I am using substitute command. [more on vim g command](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g)

```
:[range]g/pattern/cmd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, my example didn't exactly capture my issue. Oftentimes I don't have '05_sub_5_not_train' as a line, I might have something like '05_sub_5_4678821_train', '05_sub_5_074212_train', etc, where there will be a variable string in between the search pattern (sub_5 in this case) and the replace pattern (train) which complicates things a bit, do you have any recommendations for this case?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank-you very much!

Comment: Note that `s/train/not_train == s/train/not_&`

Answer (score 1):

We can also use positive lookbehind regex, like this:

```
:%s/\v(_sub_5)@<=_train/no_train/g

\v ......................... very magic (avoiding escapes)
() ......................... we are grouping the pattern where subs should occur
@<= ........................ if the preceding group matchas substitute what follows
```

Of course, we can change the range; `'<,'>` instead of `%` makes the substitution over the selected area.

I am referencing here an external [link](https://www.inputoutput.io/lookbehind-lookahead-regex-in-vim/) but you can also make research on positive and negative look assertions.

Another interesting thing to do if you are using neovim is enabbling the `inccommand` option, it allows you to se the substitution as you type your command.